# TPanel.AutoSize does not work with nested panels in a special configuration

Tags: delphi, autosize, delphi-10.4-sydney, tpanel

In a Delphi 10.4.2 win-32 VCL Application in Windows 10, I use several nested `TPanel`:

Paste these controls on an empty form:

```
object Panel1: TPanel
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 494
  Height = 299
  Align = alClient
  BevelOuter = bvNone
  TabOrder = 0
  ExplicitLeft = 40
  ExplicitTop = 140
  ExplicitWidth = 185
  ExplicitHeight = 41
  object Splitter1: TSplitter
    Left = 222
    Top = 0
    Height = 299
    Align = alRight
    Color = clSilver
    ParentColor = False
    ExplicitLeft = 280
    ExplicitTop = 112
    ExplicitHeight = 100
  end
  object CardPanel1: TCardPanel
    Left = 225
    Top = 0
    Width = 269
    Height = 299
    Align = alRight
    ActiveCard = Card1
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Caption = 'CardPanel1'
    Ctl3D = False
    ParentCtl3D = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 272
    ExplicitHeight = 282
    object Card1: TCard
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 269
      Height = 299
      Caption = 'Card1'
      CardIndex = 0
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = 1
      ExplicitTop = 1
      ExplicitWidth = 298
      ExplicitHeight = 280
      object pnlBackSide: TPanel
        AlignWithMargins = True
        Left = 10
        Top = 10
        Width = 249
        Height = 263
        Margins.Left = 10
        Margins.Top = 10
        Margins.Right = 10
        Margins.Bottom = 0
        Align = alTop
        AutoSize = True
        Color = clBlue
        ParentBackground = False
        TabOrder = 0
        object pnlFront: TPanel
          AlignWithMargins = True
          Left = 2
          Top = 2
          Width = 245
          Height = 259
          Margins.Left = 1
          Margins.Top = 1
          Margins.Right = 1
          Margins.Bottom = 1
          Align = alClient
          AutoSize = True
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          ParentBackground = False
          TabOrder = 0
          ExplicitWidth = 274
          ExplicitHeight = 243
          object lblBlaBla: TLabel
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 3
            Top = 3
            Width = 239
            Height = 13
            Align = alTop
            Alignment = taCenter
            Caption = 'BLA BLA'
            ExplicitWidth = 39
          end
          object listboxTest: TListBox
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 19
            Width = 225
            Height = 55
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 0
            Align = alTop
            BevelInner = bvNone
            ItemHeight = 13
            TabOrder = 0
            ExplicitWidth = 254
          end
          object Button1: TButton
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 78
            Width = 225
            Height = 25
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Top = 4
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 0
            Align = alTop
            Caption = 'Button1'
            TabOrder = 1
            ExplicitWidth = 254
          end
          object Button3: TButton
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 136
            Width = 225
            Height = 25
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Top = 4
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 0
            Align = alTop
            Caption = 'Button3'
            TabOrder = 2
            ExplicitWidth = 254
          end
          object Button4: TButton
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 165
            Width = 225
            Height = 25
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Top = 4
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 0
            Align = alTop
            Caption = 'Button4'
            TabOrder = 3
            ExplicitWidth = 254
          end
          object Button2: TButton
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 107
            Width = 225
            Height = 25
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Top = 4
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 0
            Align = alTop
            Caption = 'Button2'
            TabOrder = 4
            ExplicitWidth = 254
          end
          object pnlComboBack: TPanel
            AlignWithMargins = True
            Left = 10
            Top = 194
            Width = 225
            Height = 21
            Margins.Left = 10
            Margins.Top = 4
            Margins.Right = 10
            Margins.Bottom = 4
            Align = alTop
            AutoSize = True
            BevelOuter = bvNone
            TabOrder = 5
            ExplicitWidth = 254
            object cbbTest: TComboBox
              Left = 0
              Top = 0
              Width = 225
              Height = 21
              Margins.Left = 10
              Margins.Top = 4
              Margins.Right = 10
              Margins.Bottom = 4
              Align = alClient
              Style = csDropDownList
              ItemIndex = 0
              TabOrder = 0
              Text = 'Select an item'
              Items.Strings = (
                'Select an item')
              ExplicitWidth = 254
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then run the compiled app und you get something like this:

[image]

You can see that the panel `pnlBackSide` does not auto-size although its property `AutoSize` is set to `True`. Why?

How to make the panel `pnlBackSide` auto-size?

Comment: `pnlFront` has both `Align = alClient` and `AutoSize = True`. The first one says "Please, use all space of your parent, that is, be as large as you can". The last one says, "Please use no more space than your children require, that is, be as small as you can". The poor Delphi VCL cannot accommodate both your wishes at the same time.

Comment: It is true, both wishes are a LOGICAL DILEMMA and cannot be fulfilled at the SAME TIME. Maybe it is better to fulfill them consecutively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andreas correctly observed, the properties `pnlFront.Align = alClient` and `pnlFront.AutoSize = True` are a LOGICAL DILEMMA (as they are CONFLICTING) and thus cannot be executed at the same time. So the solution is to execute them **consecutively** by setting them to `pnlFront.Align = alNone` and `pnlFront.AutoSize = False` at design-time. And then at run-time, execute them consecutively:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pnlFront.AutoSize := True;
  pnlFront.Align := alClient;
end;
```

Also, to compensate for `pnlComboBack.Margins.Bottom`, also `pnlBackSide.AutoSize` must be set to `False` at design-time, and then to `True` at run-time (in the correct order):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pnlFront.AutoSize := True;
  pnlBackSide.AutoSize := True;
  pnlFront.Align := alClient;
end;
```

So the result is now perfect:

[image]